# Keep track of all files accessed by a specific process?

Tags: files, privileges, skype, privacy

There has recently been a (publicly unconfirmed) [report that Skype is accessing files that it shouldn't be, without user intervention](http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/comments/1o7o1u/skype_under_investigation_in_luxembourg_over_link/ccpkyzf). I have no idea if this is the case with Skype on linux, but it would be good to be able to find out. Is there a way to keep track of all files accessed by a specific process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch your process through `strace`:

```
strace -fe open skype
```

You will see the list of each `open()` syscall, that is every file (or connection) the processes opens during its life.

Looking at currently opened file descriptors will not provide a log but only a "snapshot" of what the process accesses right now.

Answer (score 2):

Given the PID of the Skype process, you can do:

```
for fd in /proc/$skype_pid/fd/*;do
    echo -n "File descriptor $fd points to "
    readlink "$fd"
done
```

For a given process, `/proc/$PID/fd` contains symbolic links to all the files the process currently has open. The links are named after the file descriptor number. So, to find a out where a process is getting its stdin for example, you can `readlink /proc/$pid_of_process/fd/0`. The above will tell you about all files opened by the Skype process.

If you're not sure about the PID of your process, try

```
$ pgrep skype
```

first to find out.

This will only work on systems that have a procfs, of which GNU/Linux is one.